# is there anyway to load sonarqube global permission and configuration as code?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I am trying to make a better automatically ci with jenkins containing a stage for code scanning with sonarqube.

i am using for the installation and deployment flowing environment:

- sonarqube v 7.9.x (Docker Image from the officially SQ docker hub ) -
- crowd plugin 2.1.3
- jenkins 2.249.3
- kubernetes 1.17

everythig is fine and works good, but one of annoying things , that maybe happen, when deleting/new creating PVC and lost actual configuration, that i have configured in sonarqube UI , specifically the groups/users permissions matrix  for example : users permissions for Quality Profiles/Gates administration and Execute Analysis, as in this image here [global permissions matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gex32.png).

to avoid this, the best solution is to load such confugration from a git repo (which is in k8s with flux synchronised ),
i am wondering if there a way to define such confgrations as code and not only from UI (i have searched in main sonar.properties and in crowd plugin configraion but nothing helped)

can anyone help out?

Comment: You can make use of permission template in SonarQube for such cases. https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/

Comment: @SouravAtta yes but can I load  every time such templates during Deployment for SQ direkt as file (from a git repo or something like that)

Comment: You can use sonarqube api once you created permission template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no options to define such configurations as code and keep it in a git repo. the best options in this situation is to keep all configurations in a any kind of available persistent storage (such as PVC in kubernetes).